# How to skip remaining/rest steps if condition is not matched in first step of cucumber file

Tags: cucumber-java

currently I am using Cucumber selenium Java .
I have created one cucumber feature with scenario outline.
But at first step i want to check value. 
And if value is true only then i want to execute other steps.
If value false then i want to skip remaining steps

```
Scenario Outline: 
When I am on "status" page
And I navigate to "status" page
When I click on "button"
Examples:
| status|
| true|
| false |
```

Answer (score 0):

For the Step definition example:

```
Scenario Outline: 
When I am on "status" page
And I navigate to "status" page
When I click on "button"
Examples:
| status|
| true|
| false |
```

Add conditional statements out of the feature file. The important thing here is the difference between the two status types

```
When('I am on "$status" page') do | status |
      if status== 'true'
         method_true
      else 
         if status== 'false'
            method_false
         else
            raise 'Unknown status'
         end
      end
    end
```

Comment: Thanks for update. I will use above code and let you know

Comment: @Shashi Ok. Please let me know if you face any issue. Once done could you please mark the above answer as useful. Thank you

Comment: Hi @Mebin Joe, lihave implemented this type of code already but when we see the report it will show step is in pass because we handle it in if else condition.

Comment: I want to skip step should be mentioned in report too

Comment: @Shashi To be clear, you need to show the skipped step in report or vice-versa ?

Comment: @Shashi Is this report in jenkins ? what is the kind of report/plugin?

Comment: @Shashi If you are using cucumber-reports, I would suggest you to use cucumber-extent-report. https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-cucumber-framework/cucumber-extent-report/